# Оптимизация цикла и вложенного условия

Tags: php

Есть цикл который выводит из БД инфу. Выводит по очереди.
В одном из полей есть ключевая метка в после, до которой инфу выводить не нужно, а после нее нужно. Чтобы узнать номер этой записи нужно сделать цикл с проверкой положения этой метки и только после этого сделать цикл вывода данных.

Метка стоит только в одной записи.  И все что до этой записи не нужно выводить.
При простом условии получается что я могу вывести только то что до метки.
И метка может быть а может и не быть

Возможноли оптимизировать код чтобы не было двух циклов прохода по выборке из БД?

Comment: А чем вам обычное условие внутри цикла не угодило?

Comment: Заведите флаг, изначально `false`. Появилась метка - выводите запись и ставьте флаг в `true`. Если далее флаг `true` - выводите запись.

Comment: Метка стоит только в одной записи. И все что до этой записи не нужно выводить. И метка может быть а может и не быть

Comment: а какое должно быть поведение если нету метки? Выводим все? Из описания вашего вопроса это не совсем понятно.

Comment: да выводить все

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно попробовать накапливать информацию для вывода в некоторую переменную до попадания на метку, а после попадания на метку (если таковая будет) очищать значение этой переменной, а уже после окончания цикла выводить накопленную информацию.

Схематичный пример (за основу взят сэмпл от @u_mulder ):

```
$output = '';
foreach ($ar as $item) {
    if ($item['metka'] == 1) {
        $output = '';
    }
    $output .= $item['value'];
}
echo $output;
```

Можно это дело вынести в отдельную функцию/метод:

```
function getOutputString(array $data, callable $func, $tagKey = 'metka', $tagValue = 1) {
    $output = '';
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        if ($row[$tagKey] == $tagValue) {
            $output = '';
        }
        $output .= $func($item);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Пример вызова:

```
$ar = [
    ['metka' => 0, 'value' => 2],
    ['metka' => 1, 'value' => 3],
    ['metka' => 0, 'value' => 4],
];

$output = getOutputString($ar, function($row) { return $row['value'];} ); // output: 34
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот вам гипотетический код, так как из вашего вопроса неясны начальные данные:

```
$ar = [
    ['metka' => 0, 'value' => 2],
    ['metka' => 1, 'value' => 3],
    ['metka' => 0, 'value' => 4],
];
$output = false;
foreach ($ar as $item) {
    if ($item['metka'] == 1) {
        $output = true;
    }

    if ($output) {
        echo $item['value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: а что будет если нет этой метки?

Comment: Если метки не будет - ничего не выведется. В этом случае придется еще раз пройтись по результатам.  С этим ничего не сделать. Можете выводить результаты в два буфера - в одном все, в другом все после метки. По итогам цикле выяснить - какой из буферов вывести на экран.

Comment: Или выводить в один буфер но при обнаружении метки его обнулить и заполнять заново с того места где есть метка. )))    ну вот к этому варианту я и склоняюсь.